Why is it "an outside example"?

Anything which required judging would also be restricted. One reason for this is the difficulty of obtaining of obtaining fair and accurate judges. An ... example of this is the case of Jacqueline de Bief, a former world figure skating champion.

The choices are, A. extreme, B. outside, C. upset, D. unlimited.
It's weird to me how the answer is B. outside. Can anyone explain how it is outside?
Forgive me for my bad English. I'm currently learning and still mistake grammar usages.

The 'case of Jacqueline du Bief' presumably refers to when she was controversially awarded a medal in the 1952 Olympics, that many thought undeserved (one judge gave her 6.0 even after she fell twice, and du Bief later wrote that the American Sonya Klopfer deserved the title). I would choose 'extreme', and if I were you I would ask your teacher or the person who created the test. It looks like an error.

Thank you for your comment. I was pretty confused at this answer, now with some assurance I could complain it to my teacher.

Note that your question is not about grammar. You are being asked to judge which of the word choices is most appropriate, and certainly in this context it's "extreme". C and D don't fit, but the phrase "an outside example" might be natural in other contexts. Students frequently have good cause to question their teachers' answers.

If the subject being discussed was not Olympic skating, then 'outside' (i.e. unrelated) might be OK as an answer. Was there more text than you showed?

Are you saying that someone or someone told you that “outside” is the correct answer? or just that you’re confused about why it is one of the choices? please edit to make it clear.

@noone Please check if it is "outside" or outstanding.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please check the answer on this site. It is "extreme". Maybe OP's site made a mistake. https://www.scribd.com/doc/175009838/Paper-3-Use-of-English-ONLY-PART-1-Vocabulary-with-Answers

"the difficulty of obtaining of obtaining " Is this error from the original or it is yours?

The Source Material
I was actually able to find a document OP's example is quoted from (many English learning resources seem to have stolen it from each other), and it does confirm my suspicions! The document appears to be a worksheet for ESL learners: a multiple choice exercise about using common phrases and synonyms idiomatically and correctly.

The text is an (invented) article or report about the Olympic Games and solving their judging problems by eliminating all subjective events, which the middle paragraph argues by discussing past difficulties related to judging in high-level competition. First, let's look at some context on that controversy, because unfortunately fine details about a 1952 figure skating story are necessary.
Context on Jacqueline du Bief

"Weak in figures, but an innovative free skater, Jacqueline du Bief
greatest figure skating moment came in 1952, shortly after she had won
a bronze medal at the Oslo Olympics, when she won the World
Championship in Paris. Although du Bief landed the first-ever double
Lutz by a woman, it was a controversial victory as she fell twice
during her free skate. She was given a 6.0 [the maximum score] by one judge despite this,
and even the French fans pelted the ice with various items to protest
the decision. Du Bief later wrote in her book Thin Ice, that American
Sonya Klopfer deserved the title."

Olympedia
[added context on 6.0 being the highest is mine]


The case of Jacqueline du Bief is an example of one disadvantage of competition judging; that is to say, judges can make the wrong subjective decisions. Du Bief won the World Championship in 1952 because the International Skating Union's judges came to the wrong decision1. Now, it's important to note that although the source I quoted was from Olympic history archives, du Bief's controversy was in the World Championship of Figure Skating ("Worlds"), NOT the Olympics.

"Wrong" Answers

Anything which required judging would also be restricted. One reason
for this is the difficulty of obtaining fair and accurate
judges. An (extreme/outside/upset/unlimited) example of this is the
case of Jacqueline de Bief, a former world figure skating champion.

Unlimited
Our word must describe the example, a.k.a. du Bief's case, so "unlimited" doesn't make sense because we aren't talking about any kind of limit or infinite quantity.
Upset
Now, "upset" is a bit of a tricky inclusion, because it could be plausible if we think about an upset victory, as in a notably favored opponent being beaten by du Bief, which would be an upset. Du Bief later said  that Sonya Klopfer should have won the event, so if du Bief was considerably less favored to win than Klopfer, then her win at Worlds over Klopfer would be considered an upset. From an English language perspective, though, most native speakers would say "an example that involved an upset..." or "an example of an upset" rather than "an upset example", and the fact that du Bief's win could be called an upset isn't even relevant to the report on judging anyway.
Was her win an upset at all? If we look even deeper into figure skating history, Klopfer had scored one position higher than du Bief at Worlds in 1950, one position lower than her at Worlds in 1951, and one position lower than her at the summer Oslo Games where du Bief won bronze. The two seemed closely matched, and du Bief was regularly achieving podium finishes on the world stage. It feels wrong to call her win at Worlds in 1952 an "upset" when by all accounts she stood a very good chance2 of winning.
"Correct" Answers
Extreme
The worksheets in question all mark "extreme" as correct. Does "extreme" make sense? Well, "an extreme example of this is the case of..." is a commonly used English sentence starter to introduce a drastic instance, so yes, that would make sense. For all intents and purposes, "an extreme example of this" is a good idiomatic expression to use and it seems to fit here.
My only complaint would be that this is hardly the most extreme example available, as the Olympic Games are rife with memorable judging controversies, and if this document was written in 2013 then a 1952 controversy is a poor choice. You could argue that the fact that the text mentions a rumor3 about a sexual motive for fraud makes it extreme, but that feels a bit subjective, and the next answer seems indisputably accurate.
Outside
The question asks for why "outside" would be the correct answer on the worksheet, which it turns out is not true. But if someone were to argue that "outside" is the best answer in this specific case, I think they would have a valid point. Looking even deeper, in the phrase

One reason for this is the difficulty of obtaining of obtaining fair
and accurate judges. An outside example of this is the case of [...]

, the example of du Bief is "outside" the surrounding context: the Olympic Games. Remember, du Bief's controversy was during the World Championship, but this report is about judging in the Olympics. Notice also that the report calls du Bief a former World Champion, which if you happen to know competitive figure skating well, is a title awarded at Worlds, not the Olympics. Therefore, it makes sense to say du Bief's situation is an outside example, not internal to the Olympics. This to me is more compelling than "extreme", since it's not immediately obvious what is so extreme about du Bief's case, but the externality is obvious if you know the context.

1. That is the opinion of the author of the report, anyway. My surface-level research found no concurring sources for the judging being faulty besides the mentioned public outrage over du Bief's high score.
2. Also, consider that at Worlds in 1951, du Bief had finished in 2nd place. The world champion, Jeannette Altwegg of Great Britain, did not return for Worlds 1952, so on paper, du Bief did not need to surpass any previous World Championship competitors for her win in 1952. Hardly an underdog story.
3. The report also says she got offered higher scores for "an amorous adventure", which not only replaces the actual story of her controversy with a tabloid rumor, I also couldn't even find any online records of any newspaper reporting that.
Sources/More Information

The Worksheet in question, including the answers on page 2
Olympedia page for Jacqueline du Bief
Figure skating's former 6.0 judging system
Overview of Sonya Klopfer's career
Results tables for Worlds 1950, 1951, and 1952
2002 Salt Lake City Olympic Figure Skating Scandal (which would have made a much better example in my opinion)


This site gives the correct answer as "extreme". Maybe OP's site made a mistake. https://www.scribd.com/doc/175009838/Paper-3-Use-of-English-ONLY-PART-1-Vocabulary-with-Answers

@JamesMathai wow, good catch. I've edited to address that. Honestly, outside should have been removed from the answer pool, then extreme would clearly be the best.
